# Partial scroll follow on a long jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery dialog that I tried to implement a type of scroll follow on. First attempt was using `position:fixed` but resulted in one of my taller dialogs being cut of at the bottom and the user unable to get there because scrolling only scroll the background.

Next attempt was resetting `position` option on the dialog to `center` on resize and scroll events.

This had the same affect as the first.

The effect I'm looking for is when the dialog bottom is off screen, scrolling makes the dialog scroll with the background UNTIL the whole dialog is visible then locks and allows the background only to continue scrolling.

This of course would have to work in reverse if the top gets cut off after they scroll to the bottom.

Please suggest some starting code.